# set checkbox and span in the same line and add a clickevent to the span

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I am kind of embarrassed that I can't find a solution to this simple task.

It is easy to make a checkbox and a span-tag in the same line, which what I have done liek this:

```
<label class='checkbox' for='visible_1'>
    <input id='visible_1' class='visible' type='checkbox'>
    <span>Layer_1</span>
</label>
```

I set a function to the checkbox, which show/hide the layer_1 and works pretty good.
I also set a event with jQuery to the span-tag, which show some text in the website, but then I got a problem, I can't "touch" the text of span, the checkbox kinda of blocks the text, no matter where I click, as long as I click in the line, which checkbox and span are in, I can only select the checkbox.

It seems like the checkbox takes the whole line and the click event on span-tag is blocked by checkbox.

I don't know how it can be done, cause I don't want the checkbox to take a line and the span-tag another, it's even worse.

Comment: Please, post a working code snippet.

Comment: Is it mandatory for you to have `span` inside  `label`? you can place the `span` outside the label and it should work (they will stay on the same line and you will be able to click the `span`)

Or when clicking `span` you want to check/uncheck the checkbox and at the same time show some text in the website?

Comment: @SergeyVorobey thank you for ur answer, but if I put the span outside of label, it won't be in the same line anymore. Actually I learned it on the Stack Overflow to put the span in the label so I can get the checkbox and the text of span in the same line

Comment: As Luis said. We need to see more of your code to help (your function, dependencies, etc.)

Comment: @MinXIE With default styles it should be on the same line (I just tried it), probably smth in your css breaks it. 
Just a guess (you can put the span outside the label, for them to be siblings, and try to set for their parent `display: flex` or set `float:left` for the label)

Answer (score 0):

One inherent behavior of the `label` element is to act as a touch target for its associated field:

> When a `<label>` is clicked or tapped, and it is associated with a form control, the resulting click event is also raised for the associated control. -- [MDN Element docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)

However, the default `display` attribute of a `label` element is "inline", which means they will normally appear on the same line as other "inline" elements, like `input`s:

```html
<input id='visible_1' class='visible' type='checkbox'>
<label for="visible_1">Layer_1</label>
```

It may be that your site has some style overrides to make `label` a block element, which would make sense if your normal use case is to wrap elements and their captions in a `label` element; it's common to want these controls on separate lines. If that's the case, then you can use CSS to restore the default behavior--something like:

```
.my-inline-label-section label {
  display: inline;
}
```